# Incremental search for text from the command line

Tags: startup

I'm trying to create a zsh alias that will start vim and search backwards from the end of the file for a given string. I learnt about `+normal` and can do something like this to start vim at the end of the file:

```
vim "+normal G" log
```

But I'm not able to follow that by an incremental search. The following *does* work (with a literal CR) from the command line:

```
vim "+normal G?TEST^M" log
```

But I can't get this to work with an alias, probably because of the literal carriage return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend breaking this up into multiple commands. This works for me:

```
vim log -c "normal G" -c "?TEST"
```

This doesn't need a carriage return since `"?test"` is treated as an ex command, not a normal mode command.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "normal" at all, as Ex-"?" takes an address.

```
vim log '+$?TEST'
```

> because of the literal carriage return

When you really want a carriage return, you can use "execute". The following is much longer but also works:

```
vim log '+exe "normal! G?TEST\<CR>"'
```